# How to use a column name from mixin class inside backref(.., order_by=..) with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I modify the Base class to include three default columns which all my tables have:

```
class Base(object):
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created  = Column(DateTime, default=func.current_timestamp())
    date_modified = Column(DateTime, default=func.current_timestamp(),
                                     onupdate=func.current_timestamp())
```

I have a one-to-many relationship between two columns:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    name          = Column(Text)
    password      = Column(Text)

    items = relationship("Item", backref=
                 backref('user', order_by=date_modified),
                                 cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    user_id       = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    title         = Column(Text)
```

This used to work fine, if I had date_created and date_modified columns explicitly defined within each table's class. However, when inheriting from the Base, it does not work and I get the following error:

> **NameError**: name '**date_modified**' is not defined

How can I sort the backref relationship using `order_by=column_from_mixin` (`order_by=date_modified`)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either of these:

```
backref('user', order_by=lambda: User.date_modified)
backref('user', order_by='User.date_modified')
```

Class attribute could be accessed using the class name, `User.date_modified`, but the class itself is still not defined at that point.  Providing callable (the second case is converted to callable internally) postpones name resolution till the mappings are first used, at which point all the mapped classes are defined.

Comment: Hi @AudriusKazukauskas. Thank you for the answer. Can you elaborate and explain it though? What's the logic here? How does this work?

Comment: Hi again @audriusKazukauskas. Thank you very much for the explanation. Really appreciate your kind help!